# Table format using divs

Tags: html, css

```
<table style="width: 100%">
<tr>
<td class="left">Left side content </td>
<td class="right">Right side content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Using the above code I'm able to make the two divs float left and right without breaking anything. If I use the float: left or float: right attributes, things break because position: changes. One thing I was told recently was tables are old news and using divs in its place are new. But could someone explain to me how I can go about achieving the same result I get from the above table example in divs?

Comment: those aren't divs. they're table cells, and you should NOT be floating table cells.

Comment: if you have a chance to use CSS frameworks  then check [this](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Comment: check out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Marc B, I removed the divs and appended the class to show simpler example. left and right class are not floating, they are simply left and right align classes. The table in the post isn't of much importance, just giving an example

Comment: @F.Müller, thanks for the resource! This has been an issue some time now I couldn't find resources on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two divs and set their display property to inline-block:

```css
div {
    display:inline-block;
    background: #999;
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div>Left side content</div><div>Right side content</div>
```

You can also float both divs:

```css
div {
    float:left;
    background: #999;
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div>Left side content</div><div>Right side content</div>
```

And then there's flexbox

```css
 .flex {
     width: 100%;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-flex-direction: row;
     flex-direction: row;
 }
 .flex > div {
     -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
     flex: 1 1 auto;
     background: #999;
 }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div>Left side content</div>
    <div>Right side content</div>
</div>
```